# How to use mod_rewrite to rewrite local domains?

Tags: .htaccess

How to rewrite domain from:

```
"localhost/test/?p=1" to "localhost/test/yoyoyo"
```

and

```
"localhost/test/?p=2" to "localhost/test/gogogo"
```

Comment: _“Help me!”_ - please go read [ask]. This is not a code-writing service, we expect you to show a proper initial effort. Do research, try something, _then_ report here with what your results were.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you simply rewrite each incoming request to its desired target:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?test/yoyoyo/?$ /test/?p=1 [END]
RewriteRule ^/?test/gogogo/?$ /test/?p=2 [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This implementation will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

This obviously only makes sense for a static set of URLs to be rewritten. For larger, dynamic sets you want to implement a routing script. That script is executed regardless of the specific request and compares the URL it has been requested with against entries in a database, then performs a redirection or whatever action you want. That is much slower, obviously, but offers more flexibility.